# Is there a way to delete a folder from firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter project. I was able to create code to delete firebase user, delete database documents, but I can't seem to figure out how to delete a firebase folder. I saw a post from years ago saying this feature did not exist. I would be surprised if that was still the case.

The folder I am trying to delete is called 'users/images'

Comment: By `folder` do you mean `collection`?

Comment: I made a mistake, I mean folder in firebase

Comment: I don't know how to edit my question

Comment: Hey Alice, there's a small `edit` link under your question so that you can make changes. Please update your question to clarify. Since Firebase consists of 18 products, many of which support folder-like structures, it might be helpful if show code or a screenshot of the thing you want to delete.

Comment: Firebase is a platform that consists of many products.  Are you referring to "Cloud Storage for Firebase", which provides file storage for applications?